# Typescript project linking Typescript frameworks

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have multiple Typescript frameworks used by all my Typescript projects following that sort of schema:

TS framework 1 > used by > TS framework 2 > used by > TS project 1

For now everything is in the same folder since that's the only way I could make it work but my question is this:

Is it possible to have all those different frameworks in their own project folders and have my "TS project 1" reference them all as if they were local within that project?

Or is the only solution to compile those frameworks and use them as JS library in the project?

Comment: They should be published in compiled form with `.d.ts`

Comment: So if TS project 1 depends on TS framework 1 to work it must have TS framework 1 files within its own local project folder or as javascript files with d.ts as external dependency so in other words external dependencies for TS project cannot be in any case TS based but only JS correct? if so it's kind of a limitation I think.